# How to apply if condition in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Below is my `LINQ`

I want to re-write my `LINQ` as if `flag` is `true` then fetch all the records else apply `.skip()` & `take()` as mentioned here

```
    public IEnumerable<ReportMapper> FetchReports(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int docMode, int pageNumber, bool flag )
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<ReportMapper> reports;
            using (var entities = new DatabaseEntities1())
            {
                IQueryable<ReportMapper> query;
                if (docMode > 0)
                {
                    query = (from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                             join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                             join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                             orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                             where c.AssignedDate >= startDate && c.AssignedDate <= endDate && c.StatusId == docMode
                             select new ReportMapper()
                             {
                                 DocumentName = d.FolderName,
                                 AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate,
                                 ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                                 ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                             }).Skip(pageNumber * 10).Take(50);
                }
                else
                {
                    query = (from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                             join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                             join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                             orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                             where c.AssignedDate >= startDate && c.AssignedDate <= endDate
                             select new ReportMapper()
                             {
                                 DocumentName = d.FolderName,
                                 AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate,
                                 ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                                 ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                             }).Skip(pageNumber * 10).Take(50);
                }


                reports = query.ToList<ReportMapper>();

                return reports;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
```

But no clue how will I do this.

**Note**:-
Please note that the var `docMode` in the above query is used for checking whether to apply the third condition in where clause or not (Check my where clause that's all together different)

Is there a better way to do without using if-else ladder.

Comment: You are using `Skip...Take` in both branches, so i dont understand the difference.

Comment: Just set `query` to the desired Linq and then check if `flag` is `flase` and just apply the `Skip` and `Take` like `if(!flag) query = query.Skip(pageNumber * 10).Take(50);`

Comment: You could also combine the two Linq queries by doing `&& (c.StatusId == docMode || docMode <= 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simplify your queries to this:

```
public IEnumerable<ReportMapper> FetchReports(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int docMode, int pageNumber, bool flag)
{
    using (var entities = new DatabaseEntities1())
    {
        IQueryable<ReportMapper> reports = 
                  from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                  join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                  join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                  orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                  where c.AssignedDate >= startDate && c.AssignedDate <= endDate
                    && (docMode <= 0 || c.StatusId == docMode)
                  select new ReportMapper()
                  {
                      DocumentName = d.FolderName,
                      AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate,
                      ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                      ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                  };

        if(!flag)
            reports = reports.Skip(pageNumber * 10).Take(50);

        return reports.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the `Skip` and `Take` part inside of a `if(!flag)` condition.

Comment: Actually you cannot apply the `r => c.StatusId == docMode` since `ReportMapper` doesn't have `StatusId `, and there's no `c` in that scope.  You'd also have to defer the `select` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
    public IEnumerable<ReportMapper> FetchReports(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int docMode, int pageNumber, bool flag) {
        try {
            IEnumerable<ReportMapper> reports;
            using (var entities = new DatabaseEntities1()) {
                var query = (from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                    join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                    join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                    orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                    where c.AssignedDate >= startDate && c.AssignedDate <= endDate && (docMode <= 0 || c.StatusId == docMode)
                    select new ReportMapper() {
                        DocumentName = d.FolderName,
                        AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate,
                        ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                        ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                    });
                if (!flag)
                    query = query.Skip(pageNumber*10).Take(50);
                reports = query.ToList<ReportMapper>();

                return reports;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this after your query:

```
if (!flag) query = query.Skip(pageNumber * 10).Take(50);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                query = (from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                         join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                         join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                         orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                         where c.AssignedDate >= startDate && c.AssignedDate <= endDate && c.StatusId == docMode
                         select new ReportMapper()
                         {
                             DocumentName = d.FolderName,
                             AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate,
                             ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                             ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                         });
if(!flag){
   query = query.Skip(pageNumber * 10).Take(50);
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to do the `Skip` and `Take` when `flag` is `false`, not `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = (from c in entities.tDocumentStatus
                         join d in entities.tTOCStructures on c.DocumentId equals d.DocumentID
                         join e in entities.tUsers on d.LastUpdatedBy equals e.UserUID
                         orderby c.AssignedDate descending
                         where c.AssignedDate >= startDate && c.AssignedDate <= endDate && (docMode <=0 || c.StatusId == docMode)
                         select new ReportMapper()
                         {
                             DocumentName = d.FolderName,
                             AssignedDate = c.AssignedDate,
                             ReviewStatus = c.tStatu.StatusName,
                             ActionPerformedBy = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName
                         });

if(!flag){
   query = query.Skip(pageNumber * 10).Take(50);
}
```

Comment: The question is not about how to simplify the query, but how to conditionally apply the `Skip` and `Take`.

Comment: Didnt understand the question. Thanks for po

Comment: That's better, but it should be `if(!flag)`.